# Braces of if clause on next line

Tags: webstorm

While my Settings/Editor/Code Style/JavaScript/if() statement/Force braces is set to "Always" I am still forced a bracket style like this:

```
if (this.root===null) {

}
```

Is there any other setting I should change to make the 1st brace appear next line other than upper setting?

Comment: "Force braces" is to include braces even when there's only a single line inside the block, to prevent writing `if (foo) bar`. It's not about the positioning of them. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-code-style-javascript.html

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Wraping and Braces -> Braces placement -> Next Line

Comment: This settings you mentioned are all "Next Line" but still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Live Template overriding these setting as

```
if ($condition$){
$END$
}
```

So I corrected this template as

```
if ($condition$)
{
$END$
}
```

and now it works...

Answer (score 2):

Setting **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Wraping and Braces,  Braces placement/Other** to **Next line** should do the thing

[image]

Comment: I had a Lİve Template overriding this behaviour... Thank you for the screenshot anyway...

Comment: Live templates are normally formatted according to code style preferences when expanding. I can't imagine how Live Template can override formatter behavior.

Comment: I installed templates from this github source (https://github.com/blakedietz/js-live-template) and installed it by Copying es6.xml to ~/Library/Preferences/<intellij-product-install>/templates directory. The template for "if" was on the same line in this file. I think templates override settings.